# How to return a html file using JAX-RS

Tags: java, html, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I want to return an existing HTML page, I am using getResourceAsStream to get the File but somehow I am getting an error NullPointerException.
The full path of the HTML file is **(webapp/lib/userpage.html)**

This is the Method:

```
private static ServletContext context;

@POST
@Path("/login")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public InputStream login(
        @FormParam("userName") String userName,
        @FormParam("password") String password) {
    repository.login(userName, password); //Authentication
    return context.getResourceAsStream("lib/userPage.html");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the static and add `@Context` annotation to the ServletContext field.

Comment: But you should not return the HTML page like this. Let the default servlet of the server handle the static pages.

Comment: Thanks, it worked by adding  @Context and removing the static, but I dint get what did you mean by " Let the default servlet of the server handle the static pages"

Comment: The static files should be served by the container if the files are in the webapp folder of your project (assuming you're using Maven project setup). How are you serving the rest of your static files? If you are making a login, you should consider redirecting with Response.temporaryRedirect(). It's the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: Yes its a Maven Project and you were right I used  Response.temporaryRedirect and it Worked Perfectly
Thanks

Comment: FYI, according to the PRG pattern, a 304 See Other is used rather than a 307 Temporary Redirect. You can use Response.seeOther() to use a 304 instead.